# How can I optimize my javascript code?

Tags: jquery

I have created the following jquery toggle box show/hide function. But I know that I have redundant code, and I want to make it as short and effective as possible. This is just my attempt to learn to code *right* fron the start...

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="areaPta">Pretoria</a></li>
        <li><a id="areaPotch">Potch</a></li>
        <li><a id="areaJhb">JHB</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="hidden" id="pretoriaDetail">Pretoria Content</div>
    <div class="hidden" id="potchDetail">Potch Content</div>
    <div class="hidden" id="jhbDetail">JHB Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    var p = $('#areaPta');
    var po = $('#areaPotch');
    var j = $('#areaJhb');

    p.click(function (){
        $('.hidden').hide(500);
        $('#pretoriaDetail').show(500);
    });
    po.click(function (){
        $('.hidden').hide(500);
        $('#potchDetail').show(500);
    });
    j.click(function (){
        $('.hidden').hide(500);
        $('#jhbDetail').show(500);
    });

});
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As much as possible, your markup should specify the relationships between elements, rather than manually coding this data in JavaScript. You can use the `href` attribute of each `<a>` tag to specify the ID of the element that `<a>` tag is meant to affect:

```
<div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a id="areaPta" href="#pretoriaDetail">Pretoria</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="hidden" id="pretoriaDetail">Pretoria Content</div>
    ...
</div>
```

And then make your click binding much more generic:

```
$("#nav a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".hidden").hide(500);
  $($(this).attr("href")).show(500)
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot! appreciate. What does event.preventDefault(); do?

Comment: Teel me one more thing please, what is the difference in using double quotes and single quotes in jquery? "" vs '' ?

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` prevents the click event from bubbling up to the browser and affecting the URL in the address bar. There is no appreciable difference between double and single quotes in JavaScript (not jQuery, which simply a library written *in* Javascript), it's largely a matter of personal preference.

Comment: There is no difference between using single and double quotes. its more of a convention to use double quotes for attribute values in JS markup.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a JS fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jagzviruz/w3hqe/1/ which can guide you on how you can minimize the lines of code while creating more meaningful markup.
Do note that this does create multiple click handlers. You can do a better job by creating a `.on()` handler on the ul wrapping the links.

HTML

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="areaPta" href="#" rel="pretoriaDetail">Pretoria</a></li>
    <li><a id="areaPotch" href="#" rel="potchDetail">Potch</a></li>
    <li><a id="areaJhb" href="#" rel="jhbDetail">JHB</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="hidden" id="pretoriaDetail">Pretoria Content</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="potchDetail">Potch Content</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="jhbDetail">JHB Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

JS

```
var p = $('#areaPta, #areaPotch, #areaJhb') ;

p.click(function (e) {
    var targ = $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')) ;
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hidden').hide(500)
    targ.show(500);    
});
```

Comment: nice code. appreciate!

Comment: @jagzviruz you should show your code here.

Comment: what exactly does e do?

Comment: by passing multiple ids to jquery selector at once I have minimized the calls to the jquery library. This returns us an array of jQ objects on which a similar function will be called for click events.
I have used the rel attribute to identify the div to be shown and accordingly opened it.

Comment: Isn't 'rel' used incorrectly here? even though it does do the job...

Comment: The rel attribute specifies the relationship between the link document and the linked document/section. So its safe to use it. You can also use the href attribute to specify the value, but that would not be appropriate because its not exactly a link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using your current markup (I did capitalize ID's so they would match) - http://jsfiddle.net/D3e4d/3/

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clicked = $(this).text();
    $('.hidden').hide(500);
    $('[id^="' + clicked + '"]').toggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generic handler function with a little change to the markup. See below,

```
<ul id="mylinks">
    <li><a id="areaPta" data-content-id="pretoriaDetail">Pretoria</a></li>
    <li><a id="areaPotch" data-content-id="potchDetail">Potch</a></li>
    <li><a id="areaJhb" data-content-id="jhbDetail">JHB</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then the script,

```
$('#mylinks a').click (function () {
   $('.hidden').hide(500);
   $('#' + $(this).data('content-id')).show(500);
});
```

Comment: nice solution as well. Will definitely reference this is the future. Snippets here we go

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I usually declare variables that return a jquery object with a `$` prefix:

```
var $p = $('#areaPta');
```

But there is no point storing them in to a variable when they only will be used once.

In my opinion, your code is ok. The only thing I can think of right away that will reduce the redudancy would be something like:

```
<a id="areaPta" data-target="pretoriaDetail">Pretoria Content</a>

$('li a').on('click', function(e){

    var target = $(e.target).data('target');

    $('#' + target).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: thank you Johan. Appreciate your answer. Helpful

Comment: @DexterSchneider No problem, hopefully it'll be of some use

Answer (score -3):

The things you do here I would do the following way:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="whateverClass">Pretoria</a></li>
        <li><a class="whateverClass">Potch</a></li>
        <li><a class="whateverClass">JHB</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="hidden">Pretoria Content</div>
    <div class="hidden">Potch Content</div>
    <div class="hidden">JHB Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
//This will shorten things up for you a bit.
$(function() {
    $(".whateverClass").click(function (){
        //Fixed a bug here
        $('.hidden').hide(500);
        $(this).find('.hidden').show(500);
    });
});
```

However, I do not want to get into why you want this exact behavior, but at least it is a bit shorter and easier to maintain.

Comment: You're not showing and hiding each element. You'll show them all ultimately, with every click.

Comment: Woops. Thats true.. *editing*

Comment: No, he had each element individually specified for showing after hiding any that might be showing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Realized I was a bit hasty. The posted is deleted.